Does Solidity require pointer alignment in memory?
Solidity seems to allocate memory under pointers being multiples of 32. This is understandable since most allocation sizes are multiples of 32. But is it a requirement or is it fine if a Yul inline violates this convention? E.g. in Yul you can easily allocate 33 bytes: mstore(0x40, add(33, mload(0x40)), but will it cause problems for Solidity? You can also place items under non-aligned locations, e.g. my_array := add(mload(0x40), 1) (remember to initialize my_array and update 0x40), will Solidity work fine with my_array?
Edit: It seems that the legacy pipeline breaks the 32-byte alignment when calling external functions, it allocates a multiple of 32 plus 4 bytes for the selector. Via-IR on the other hand rounds up all the allocations to multiples of 32 even if a call is made. So the questions is probably more about via-IR?
